# Can I randomize message replies? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

What I am trying to do is randomize messages, i don't know how though.
I've been using the code:

```
  client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '.Ping') {
       msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
  });
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to make it send random replies when a command is executed on Discord.

Comment: You can keep replies in an array, then choose a random number using `Math.random()` and then use that number as an index and fetch a reply from the array using the index.

Comment: Please do your research before asking. There are hundreds results you'd find just by a quick Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can defined list of answer in array and random of one those answer

Ex:

```js
 const answer = ['a', 'b' , 'c'];
 client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '.Ping') {
       msg.reply(answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * answer.length)]);
    }
  });
```